# How pass a variable from html to python in an easy way?

Tags: python, html, variables

I would like to know the easiest way of pass a variable in html to python. I get the variable with "input" and i only want to pass it to python, python doesn´t have to send anything to html.

Thank you!

Comment: If you are allowed to make request like `url.com/path?name1=value1&name2=value2` then these values are passed to the backend server which could be written in Python

Comment: Are you accessing the html via `requests` package you can use htmlParser like `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: This is far too vague a description to answer. You use the ptyhon `input()` function? Is it reading html? Are you using any python packages? Is this a server side form? A client side http request?

Comment: right now, i don´t have any script in python so i can use anything. And  it isn´t server side

Answer (score 6):

You can use a simple [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) web app to do this.

You can create an HTML file that has your HTML input form like this:

`index.html`

```
<form action="/get-text" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="test">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Your Flask app would look like this in it's simplest form.

`app.py`

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/get-text', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def foo():
    bar = request.form['test']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The file hierarchy should look like this:

```
- app
    - templates
        - index.html
    - app.py
```

When the user hits the `Go` button on the HTML form, the code in the `foo` function will get executed and the text will be stored in the variable `bar`.

Comment: How in the world did we get to flask when we don't even know if this a question about a server side post?

Comment: i did that, i use a "print" to watch the variable "bar" in python; but when i hit "Go", i get a new page "file:///C:/get-text" on my browser saying me that file not found and i don´t get any print in python

Comment: @AntonioMJ If your file structure is exactly like this and you are using the code that I posted in my answer this will work. I tested it. If you aren't using it, try it, make sure you have a working Flask app, and then work off of it.

Comment: i´m using Windows, Does it change something? i made a folder with the app.py and inside other folder "static" with the index.html

Comment: @AntonioMJ Rename `static` to `templates`

Comment: i get the same result, any print and a page saying me that the file was not found. i have to run the app.py in a special way? i only put "python app.py"

Comment: thanks, it works for me, but only if i return something at the end of foo function